# android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 - TextColor is white - Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have simple ListView and am populating with ArrayAdapter. But than text of ListView is white. It was black before, now I get white text. How can I fix this? It is actually right SlidingDrawer.
My code:

```
lvHoroscope = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHoroscope);

String[] horoscope = getApplication().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.horoscope);

lvHoroscope.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, horoscope));
```

[image]
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so might be you are using a `Dark theme` so the text is `white`

- ***Solution1***

*Change the theme to `Theme.Light`*

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...
</style>
```

- ***Solution2***

Just add the `textColor` to the `textView`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by using your own layout instead of the one in Android Sdk. Follow these steps:

1. Add a new layout named list_item_black_text in your project and then clear it and paste the folloing code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@android:id/text1"
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:gravity="center_vertical"
> android:textColor="#000000"
> android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
> android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
> android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
> android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
> ```

2. Change your code:

> lvHoroscope.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),
>                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, horoscope));

to

> lvHoroscope.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),
>                  R.layout.list_item_black_text, horoscope));

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm using custom layout with custom adapter, but I was just wondering why text is white :)

Comment: Thank you Leog, 
I would like to add that for API's less than 17:
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
 - Should be replaced with:
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"

Answer (score 1):

Did you use SlidingMenu library ?

if yes ? 
here's the answer to that, 
SlidingMenu uses ActionBarSherlock style which the theme is dark that's why the text color of your app turns to white.

Solution: Just add textColor to each of the listItem's textview, and see the result:

```
    android:textColor="#000000"
```

If not?
just to the Solution above anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this without needing to create anything extra would be to just modify the simple list `TextView`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, strings) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                textView.setTextColor({yourColorHere}));
                return textView;
            }
        };
```